# After hitting SUBMIT show one more input field as popup for entering what has changed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a html form. After hitting the submit button, I want some kind of popup to appear where the user can enter what he has changed. And only after that has been done, ther form should be submitted to the web server.

It's for internal usage only, so design doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spite of using submit button you just use `<type="button" onclick="function1()">`

in javascript section code:

```
function1(){
// here you can use a textbox or a prompt box to enter some value after which
//  redirect to desired page using document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

I think this will solve your problem..

Comment: ok, the prompt box as described in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp would be what I will put in the function. But how to make the prompted input field be part of the form data, so it is also submittet with the other form data?

Comment: There are many ways to do that.. One way to achieve this is "Hidden fields" consider this link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp   ... ..  You can add one <hidden field> in your form and in your javascript after getting value from prompt box you can assign this value to the hidden field's value attribute thus when you submit the form that data will also be sent..

Answer (score 0):

@user3077238, I can't comment yet, but Rupesh's answer will work.

You will want to call the original function that was in place when the user clicked submit within `function1(){}` after they provide input.

Now that `function1(){}` will be running before whatever code you had originally when the user clicked submit, you would just pass the input from the prompt to the original submit function.